# Not able to fetch correct value from array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I wish to fetch values from the following array

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($attachments); 
echo "</pre>";


    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [is_attachment] => 
                [filename] =>  Desert.jpg
                [name] =>  Desert.jpg
                [attachment] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [is_attachment] => 1
                [filename] => Hydrangeas.jpg
                [name] =>  Hydrangeas.jpg
                [attachment] => 
            )
    )
```

I used this code to fetch the values

```
foreach($attachments as $value)
    { 
        foreach($value as $values)
            { 
                echo $values[filename];
                echo "<br>";
            } 
    }
```

O/P that i got is

```
D
D
H
H
```

The desired o/p should be

```
 Desert.jpg
 Hydrangeas.jpg
```

Can anyone tell where i went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of two loops, you can get values from single loop as it's outer loop of [0],[1] etc.

```
foreach($attachments as $value)
    { 
        echo $value['filename'];
                echo "<br>"; 
    }
```